# Magento2 how to add GTM data layer scripts without extension

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

Magento2 I need to add all the datalayer script to Magento2 without any extension

How can I achieve this?

For e.g. Product Impressions script

I think this should be call on listing page, then other page

Also, for this product Impression script there is an array of 2 products, should I dynamically display all the product in this script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions example of code, the yes, those 2 products should be replaced by the list of products from the page you are currently seeing (for example, the list of products from a specific category view page, a search result page or various product sliders).